# How to autofill output column in arcmap batch process menu?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, convert, batch

Referring to the screenshot, I'd like to know how to fill the output column with unique values that either have the same name as the input files or otherwise have some unique value in each cell. If I fill in the first output cell, and then right-click and use fill, it fills the entire column with the same file name as used in the first cell, therefore I only get one output file. If I don't fill in the output column at all, I get unique file names for each cell, but they are saved to the default gdb which gives me difficulty. What I'd like to do is to save unique file names to a directory that I choose. Is there a way to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far i can recall, you can select all tables from this batch tool and copy into microsoft excel and modify input parameters of the tool in excel (apply some excel formula to change the output to lessen manual labor). After that you can select all in the tool and paste this excel rows back into the tool.

[image: demo]

Comment: Good Idea, I put the input column in excel and use the replace function to change the directory of each cell to match the desired output directory. This eliminates any need to change the actual file names. I use Excel's concatenate function to add .shp extension. I try to copy and paste the desired output column into arcmap. For a split second it shows all the cells correctly filled in, but then the paste disappears and leaves only the first cell. So close, yet so far :)

Comment: Finally! I was not paying attention to your demo image which shows that you pasted all columns, not just the output column from excel, and you first selected all rows. This did the trick.

Comment: Yap this is the select all practice.. and easy too.I think your are now done?

Comment: Thanks alot! saved a lot of time for my work !! @SIslam

Comment: The batch to itself needs a batch tool

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend to build a simple model to iterate through all rasters in your workspace and then convert each of them to Polygon.

To add an iterator, In model builder go to:
Insert > Iterators > Rasters

You final model should look like this:

[image: Model to iterate rasters]

and your Calculate Value Should look like this:

[image]

The code block:

```
def t(s):
 return 'C:\Users\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb\RasterToPoly'+s.split('.')[0]
```